# How to add shader override to render layer in Maya 2018 using python

Tags: python, maya, autodesk

I want to add a shader override of say a shader called "myBlinn" to a render layer.
So far I have been able to create a render layer and create a collection consisting of all the objects in the scene. I dont know how to create a shader override using python now. Can you guys help?

Here is the code so far.

```html
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup
rs = renderSetup.instance()
rl = rs.createRenderLayer("MyRenderSetupLayer")
c1 = rl.createCollection("meshCollection")
c1.getSelector().setPattern('**')
rs.switchToLayer(rl)
```

Answer (score 2):

here is code, tested in maya 2019.1

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup

rs = renderSetup.instance()
try: rl = rs.getRenderLayer("myRenderSetupLayer")
except: rl = rs.createRenderLayer("myRenderSetupLayer")
try: c1 = rl.getCollectionByName("meshCollection")
except:  c1 = rl.createCollection("meshCollection")

# shading group filter
try: c2 = c1.getCollectionByName("SGs")
except:  c2 = c1.createCollection("SGs")
sl2= c2.getSelector()
sl2.setFilterType(11)   # Collection Filters = Shading engines
sl2.setPattern('*') # 從上層 Collection 繼承的所有對象

# Shader Override
try: so = c2.getOverrides()[0]  # 返回 Collection 下的 Override 列表
except: so = c2.createOverride("anyName", "shaderOverride")
# assign shader
so.setShader("myBlinn")
```